# Xcode looking in wrong location for CFNetwork framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, asihttprequest

I wouldn't be surprised if this is something stupid that I'm doing... This is an iOS target project.

- MacOS: 10.7 Lion
- Xcode: 4.1
- Target: iPhone 4.3

I used ASI's ASIHTTPRequest add-in framework in a different project and it worked fine.

I've added it to the current project I'm working on and now Xcode is looking for the CFNetwork framework in a project directory instead of the SDK location. I have not added any search locations and have verified that the CFNetwork framwork location is set to "Relative to SDK" and is looking at the "System/Library/Frameworks" directory.

As you can see at the bottom of the error message, it is looking in the wrong folder for the framework—it is looking inside the project folder.

Please let me know if you have any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Error message:

> CompileC /Users/mooner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoonCo_TiltFinder-gzpflywfciaabtachdctgqaarhmu/Build/Intermediates/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDownloadCache.o ASIDownloadCache.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       cd /Volumes/One.One/Development/Cam-MoonCo_TabBar/MoonCo_CustomTabBar
>       setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
>       setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info -fdiagnostics-show-category=id -fdiagnostics-parseable-fixits -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -DDEBUG -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=**attribute**((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=**attribute**((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)**attribute**((ibaction)" -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40300 -iquote /Users/mooner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoonCo_TiltFinder-gzpflywfciaabtachdctgqaarhmu/Build/Intermediates/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/MoonCo_TiltFinder-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/mooner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoonCo_TiltFinder-gzpflywfciaabtachdctgqaarhmu/Build/Intermediates/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/MoonCo_TiltFinder-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/mooner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoonCo_TiltFinder-gzpflywfciaabtachdctgqaarhmu/Build/Intermediates/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/MoonCo_TiltFinder-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/mooner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoonCo_TiltFinder-gzpflywfciaabtachdctgqaarhmu/Build/Intermediates/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/MoonCo_TiltFinder-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/mooner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoonCo_TiltFinder-gzpflywfciaabtachdctgqaarhmu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/mooner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoonCo_TiltFinder-gzpflywfciaabtachdctgqaarhmu/Build/Intermediates/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/mooner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoonCo_TiltFinder-gzpflywfciaabtachdctgqaarhmu/Build/Intermediates/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/mooner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoonCo_TiltFinder-gzpflywfciaabtachdctgqaarhmu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Volumes/One.One/Development/Cam-MoonCo_TabBar/MoonCo_CustomTabBar -include /Users/mooner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoonCo_TiltFinder-gzpflywfciaabtachdctgqaarhmu/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/MoonCo_CustomTabBar-Prefix-ezvknrzjsqbjxdfzxcnzjkisdtlw/MoonCo_CustomTabBar-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/mooner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoonCo_TiltFinder-gzpflywfciaabtachdctgqaarhmu/Build/Intermediates/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDownloadCache.d -c /Volumes/One.One/Development/Cam-MoonCo_TabBar/MoonCo_CustomTabBar/ASIDownloadCache.m -o /Users/mooner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoonCo_TiltFinder-gzpflywfciaabtachdctgqaarhmu/Build/Intermediates/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoonCo_TiltFinder.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDownloadCache.o
>
> fatal error: cannot open file '/Volumes/One.One/Development/Cam-MoonCo_TabBar/MoonCo_CustomTabBar/CFNetwork.framework/Headers/CFHTTPMessage.h':

Comment: I never figured out why/how this happened, but I created a new project and copied all the files over to the new project. Now working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Cleaning the project via <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> solved it for me.